# Include_once in Object dont work

Tags: php, oop, include, include-path

I got a problem with php and OOP.
I tried to create a object and inside the object I tried to load data from mysql.

My files are build like this.
HTML
   |_ php
|__ objects
   |_ content

In object folder is the object file "Event". The object created in a script in php folder and the whole script is called from a html file in content.

My Problem is, that i use the object from different locations. And the include_once method wont work.

event.php:

```
<?php
include_once(ROOT.'php/db.inc.php');

class Pb1_event
{
    public $ev1_id;
    // do something
}
```

I also tried it with include_once('./../db.inc.php');. 
How should I include it ? Is it a good way to include it in this file or should I include it anywhere else ?

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting

Comment: Oh sorry:
Warning: include_once(/php/db.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/objects/Pb1_event.php on line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly what I would do is use either `__DIR__`, or better is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for absolute pathing. These are constants that will refer to your server web root. Assuming it refers to the root directory you have given to us, you would do:

`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/db.inc.php';`

But to gain a better understanding, you should `echo` it and see how your directory paths. Also, for the "best practices" you should use autoloading, you can read more about it here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Define an autoload function and have it call the file you need, for example, if you need a class called DB your function might look something like this:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    if ($class == 'DB') {
        require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/db.inc.php';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` magic constants:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../db.inc.php');
include_once(__DIR__ . '/../db.inc.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to register an autoloader in the beginning of your scripts using `spl_autoload_register()`:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    include 'path/to/php/objects/' . $className . '.php';
});
```

When you want to instantiate an object, where ever you are, you just need to do:

```
$myclass = new MyClass();
```

The autoloader will load the correct class. All you need to think about is to call the files in "objects" the same as your classes. Example:

```
class Pb1_event {
}
```

filename: path/to/php/objects/Pb1_event.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for your warning:

```
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/php/db.inc.php');
```